# Why Flask-PyMongo bulk_writes method doesn't exist?

Tags: flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I have some code snippet like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from pymongo import InsertOne, UpdateOne, DeleteOne, ReplaceOne
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'MyDB'

mongo = PyMongo(app)
coll = mongo.db['collection1']

requests = []
for d in data_to_delete:
    requests.append(DeleteOne({'key1': d}))

result = coll.bulk_writes(requests)

return jsonify(result=result.deleted_count)
```

When I try to execute it, I get the error message:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'bulk_writes' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

[PyMongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) says that `Collection` object has this method, though I know that `Flask-Pymongo` is a wrapper around `PyMongo`.
What could be the problem, and how could I use `bulk_writes()` with `Flask-Pymongo` collections?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you made a typo, adding an "s" to the method name. Try `bulk_write` with no "s".

Flask-PyMongo, like PyMongo itself and the MongoDB shell, treat unknown attribute names on collections as dotted collection names, so it thinks you're trying to call a collection called `collection1.bulk_writes`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, thank you for your help and for your work too! :)